# Y scaling relative to the max value in my ChartJS chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have multiples charts and I set a max tick on my yAxes relative to a value:

```
yAxes: [{
                                gridLines: {
                                    display: true
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                    max: dataExcp[4] * 1.1,
                                    callback: function (value) {
                                        return value.toLocaleString() + " €";
                                    },
                                    fontStyle: 'bold'
                                }}
```

But "dataExcp[4]" is not always the higher value. How to change that ? I want the max value to be the reference.

[image]

We can't the start of the chart cause the max value  is calculated with the 2019 value.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by replacing "max" by "suggestedMax". ChartJS understands it's just a suggestion and deal with my problem.

```
yAxes: [{
    gridLines: {
        display: true
    },
    ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        suggestedMax: dataExcp[4] * 1.1,
        callback: function (value) {
            return value.toLocaleString() + " €";
        },
        fontStyle: 'bold'
    }
}
]
```